# How to access key value pairs in mixed nested lists and dictionaries?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

someone please show me how to access key value pairs of this sort. I want to access the "category", "question", "correct answer", "incorrect answer". I could remove the "response code" and "results" and only work with the nested dict within a list, but I wanted to try without manipulating the data. I know a for loop will be used.

```
question_data = {"response_code": 0,
                 "results": [
                     {"type": "multiple",
                      "difficulty": "medium",
                      "category": "Entertainment: Film",
                      "question": "Sign of death.",
                      "correct_answer": "Red Shirt",
                      "incorrect_answers": ["Minions", "Expendables", "Cannon Fodder"]
                      }
                      ]
```

Comment: What don't you understand? Just loop over `question_data['results']`, and access those keys of each element.

Comment: `for result in question_data['results']:` and then you can use things like `result['category']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Access "Results" with `question_data["results"]`
2. Iterate through its content
3. Get individual elements

Could be done with this:

```py
# Iterate through the list of results
for question in question_data["results"]:
  # Access the keys of the dictionary
  category = question["category"]
  question_text = question["question"]
  correct_answer = question["correct_answer"]
  incorrect_answers = question["incorrect_answers"]
  print(f"Category: {category}")
  print(f"Question: {question_text}")
  print(f"Correct Answer: {correct_answer}")
  print(f"Incorrect Answers: {incorrect_answers}")
```

```
Category: Entertainment: Film
Question: Sign of death.
Correct Answer: Red Shirt
Incorrect Answers: ['Minions', 'Expendables', 'Cannon Fodder']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use json to parse the data:

```
import pprint
import json

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)

question_data ="""{
    "response_code": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "type": "multiple",
            "difficulty": "medium",
            "category": "Entertainment: Film",
            "question": "Sign of death.",
            "correct_answer": "Red Shirt",
            "incorrect_answers": [
                "Minions",
                "Expendables",
                "Cannon Fodder"
            ]
        }
    ]
}"""

print("Pretty Print for better overview:")
pp.pprint(question_data)

y = json.loads(question_data)
# print(y)

for k,v in y.items():
    print(f"Key: {k} Value: {v}\n")
    
##############################################
print("VALUES:") # use list comprehensive loop
##############################################

# Access response_code
print("response_code:", [v for k,v in y.items() if k == "response_code"])

# Access e.g. category and the similar for other values in this list
print("category:", [v for k,v in y['results'][0].items() if k == "category"])

# Access incorrect answer level with list element 0
print("incorrect_answers:", y['results'][0]['incorrect_answers'][0])
```

Output:

```
Pretty Print for better overview:
('{\n'
 '    "response_code": 0,\n'
 '    "results": [\n'
 '        {\n'
 '            "type": "multiple",\n'
 '            "difficulty": "medium",\n'
 '            "category": "Entertainment: Film",\n'
 '            "question": "Sign of death.",\n'
 '            "correct_answer": "Red Shirt",\n'
 '            "incorrect_answers": [\n'
 '                "Minions",\n'
 '                "Expendables",\n'
 '                "Cannon Fodder"\n'
 '            ]\n'
 '        }\n'
 '    ]\n'
 '}')
Key: response_code Value: 0

Key: results Value: [{'type': 'multiple', 'difficulty': 'medium', 'category': 'Entertainment: Film', 'question': 'Sign of death.', 'correct_answer': 'Red Shirt', 'incorrect_answers': ['Minions', 'Expendables', 'Cannon Fodder']}]

VALUES:
response_code: [0]
category: ['Entertainment: Film']
incorrect_answers: Minions
```